# Intersperse a List<>

Tags: c#, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extension method for Enumerable.Intersperse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753316/extension-method-for-enumerable-intersperse)

I have a `List<string>` like this:

`"foo", "bar", "cat"`

I want it to look like this:

`"foo", "-", "bar", "-", "cat"`

Is there a C# method that does that?

Comment: See this previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753316/extension-method-for-enumerable-intersperse


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753316/extension-method-for-enumerable-intersperse

Comment: No, you'll have to write your own.

Comment: Why do you need this? Do you want to print out the values with a - between it? Then there are probably easier ways.

Comment: @PoweRoy: Because I like chaining string functions in one line, like `string.Trim().Split(',')[0].Intersperse("-");`.

Comment: @Paige that link contains superior answers to those found in this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make an extension that returns an `IEnumerable<T>` with interspersed items:

```
public static class ListExtensions {

  public static IEnumerable<T> Intersperse<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, T separator) {
    bool first = true;
    foreach (T item in items) {
      if (first) {
        first = false;
      } else {
        yield return separator;
      }
      yield return item;
    }
  }

}
```

The advantage of this is that you don't have to clutter your list with the extra items, you can just use it as it is returned:

```
List<string> words = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar", "cat" };

foreach (string s in words.Intersperse("-")) {
  Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

You can of course get the result as a list if you need that:

```
words = words.Intersperse("-").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://pastebin.com/gM9cACXP) is an implementation out of my personal toolbox. It's more general than what you require.

For your particular example, you would write

```
var list = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "cat" };
var result = list.InterleaveWith(Enumerable.Repeat("-", list.Count - 1));
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/VjeRE)**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its a custom method you would write:

```
List<string> AddDashesToList(List<string> list)
{
    if(list.Count > 1)
    { 
        var newList = new List<string>();

        foreach(item in list)
        {
           newList.Add(item);
           newList.Add("-");
        }

        newList.RemoveAt(newList.Count-1);

        return newList;
    }
    else
    {
         return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: And extra dash at the end of a list :)

Comment: An other one point: if `list` method argument is empty `foreach` simply will be ignored but `RemoveAt(-1)` will throw an exception? ;)

Comment: Sorry but what about the case when Items.Coutn == 1,  method still returns extra dash?

Comment: Again correct. Now should be fixed =)

Comment: Now looks better. Also condition `if(newList.Count > 1)` is redundant because it always will be at least 2 items because you are in up-level condition `list.Count > 1`

Comment: That's what happens when you don't test your code in VS.

Answer (score 0):

```
       public  List<string> GetNewList(List<string> list, string s)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var l in list)
        {
            result.Add(l);
            result.Add(s);
        }
        result.RemoveAt(result.Count - 1);
        return result;
    }
```

you can use this method to get you list

```
var result =   GetNewList(str,"-");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hah! I've just written something for just this purpose!

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Interleave<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] arrays)
    {
        var enumerators = arrays.Select(array => array.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
        var finished = true;
        do
        {
            finished = true;
            foreach (var enumerator in enumerators)
            {
                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    yield return enumerator.Current;
                    finished = false;
                }
            }
        } while (finished == false);
    }
```

This will interleave the specified enumerables in the order you choose. 
Then you just fill an enumerable with dashes and interleave that with the original array. It can do more complex things as well.

Answer (score 0):

A while ago I wrote an extension method for this kind of thing:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> 
    Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T> separatorFactory)
{
    var srcArr = src.ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < srcArr.Length; i++)
    {
        yield return srcArr[i];
        if(i<srcArr.Length-1)
        {
            yield return separatorFactory();
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
myList.Join(() => "-").ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

As pointed out, my previous code results to a string not an array of strings. So here's my edited code:

```
var list = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "cat" };
var result = string.Join("-", list.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
string pattern = "(-)";
string[] test = Regex.Split(result, pattern);
foreach(var str in test)
   Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Retained old code for comparison purposes:

```
 var list = new List<string> { "foo", "bar", "cat" };
 var result = string.Join("-", list.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
 Console.WriteLine(result); // prints "foo-bar-cat
```

Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145856/how-to-join-int-to-a-character-separated-string-in-net). Cheers!

Comment: This results in a string, not an array of strings

Comment: @MerickOWA Code updated. Thanks for correcting me.